# Sending one SNS push notification message to multiple devices at same time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, push-notification, nest, amazon-sns

I need to send SNS push notification to multiple devices passing the array of device tokens

Currently I'm sending the push message to SNS using this steps:

Creating the endpoint:

```
pl, err := svc.CreatePlatformEndpoint(&sns.CreatePlatformEndpointInput{
    PlatformApplicationArn: aws.String(topic),
    Token: aws.String(n.DeviceToken), // just one device token
})
```

Sending the message to endpoint:

```
params := &sns.PublishInput{
    Message:          aws.String(payload),
    TargetArn:        aws.String(*pl.EndpointArn),
    MessageStructure: aws.String("json"),
}
```

I have not seen a way to send one push message to multiple devices using just one request. Is it possible?

Like this example to illustrate:

```
pl, err := svc.CreatePlatformEndpoint(&sns.CreatePlatformEndpointInput{
    PlatformApplicationArn: aws.String(topic),
    Token: []aws.String{token01, token02, token03}, //array of device tokens
})
```

Please help me out, To send SNS push notification message to multiple devices using  TargetArn: // as array

Comment: You are correct. You will need to send the message to each device individually.

Comment: Thanks for your response - @JohnRotenstein 
Any other way to send the notification at the same time?

Comment: Loop thorugh each recipient and call the `Publish()` API once for each recipient.